# How do I check whether the sequence converges uniformly?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, divergent-series

The sequence is:
$$f_n=x^n-x^{n+1}=x^n(1-x),\quad x\in[0,1]$$
I need to check whether it converges uniformly, but I'm having doubts about the answer for $x\in(0,1)$. Below is what I've tried.

I apply Cauchy's covergence test:
\begin{align*}
&\text{for x=0,x=1}\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x^n(1-x)}=0\\
&\text{for x}\in(0,1)\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}(x\sqrt[n]{(1-x)})=x<1
\end{align*}
A series of 0's converges uniformly, and to check the rest of the inverval I evaluate:
$$\sup_{[0,1]}(x^n-x^{n+1})=\sup_{[0,1]}(\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^n(1-\frac{n}{n+1})$$
because $f_n^{max}$ is reached when $x=x_{max}=\frac{n}{n+1}$.
Now, since $x_{max}<1$,
$$\sup_{[0,1]}(\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^n(1-\frac{n}{n+1})\leq \sup_{[0,1]}((1-\frac{n}{n+1})$$
And the problem here is that the majorant series clearly diverges, which gives no information concerning convergence of the series in question.

What am i doing wrong and where do I proceed from here? Can I argue that the last inequality is strict and say that uniform convergence does follow from it?

Comment: MathJax supports backslashes for almost everything: use `\lim,\sup` to render $\lim,\sup$

Comment: @FShrike, done.

Comment: $$
\sup _{0 < x < 1} \left| {f_n (x)} \right| =  \left| {f_n \left( {\frac{n}{{n + 1}}} \right)} \right| = \left( {\frac{n}{{n + 1}}} \right)^n \frac{1}{{n + 1}} \le \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{n + 1}} \to 0.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is controlled by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n}\left(1-\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n}\dfrac{1}{n+1}.
\end{align*}
We know that
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n}\rightarrow e^{-1},
\end{align*}
so for large $n$,
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n}\left(1-\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)\leq 2e^{-1}\dfrac{1}{n+1},
\end{align*}
which tends to zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: A simple follow-up question, if you don't mind: does this argument work because $f_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Actually this argument shows that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_{n}(x)|\leq 2e^{-1}\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ for large $n$ and we conclude that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_{n}(x)|=0$, which exactly says that $f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ uniformly.